# Aplicação fecha no toque do botão

Tags: java, android

Quando uma ou mais `EditText`s estão vazias o toque no botão deveria mostrar a mensagem do `Toast`, mas a aplicação fecha. Por quê?

```java
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    int rcpNum, fckNum, abtmNum, mucBritaNum, meCimentoNum, meBritaNum, meAreiaNum;
    double dmaxNum, mfNum, sdNum;

    EditText rcpTxt, fckTxt, abtmTxt, dmaxTxt, mfTxt, mucBritaTxt, meCimentoTxt, meBritaTxt, meAreiaTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_avancado);

        rcpTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rcp_edt);
        fckTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fck_edt);
        abtmTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.abtm_edt);
        dmaxTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmax_edt);
        mfTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mf_edt);

        mucBritaTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mucbrita_edt);
        meCimentoTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mecimento_edt);
        meBritaTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mebrita_edt);
        meAreiaTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.meareia_edt);

        //Spinner
        Spinner spnSd = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_sd);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spnAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spn_sd_str, R.layout.spinner_style);
        spnAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_style);

        spnSd.setAdapter(spnAdapter);

        spnSd.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spnAdpView, View v, int sdPosition, long id) {

                        if(spnAdpView.getItemAtPosition(sdPosition).toString().equals("SD = 4,5 MPa")){ sdNum = 4.5; }
                        else if(spnAdpView.getItemAtPosition(sdPosition).toString().equals("SD = 5,5 MPa")){ sdNum = 5.5; }
                        else { sdNum = 7.5; }

                    }// fecha onItemSelected

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}
                }//fecha OnItemSelectedListener
        ); // fecha setOnItemSelectedListener
        //spinner



        // CALCULAR #######################################
                ImageButton calcTraco = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_traco);
                calcTraco.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        rcpNum = Integer.parseInt(rcpTxt.getText().toString());
                        fckNum = Integer.parseInt(fckTxt.getText().toString());
                        abtmNum = Integer.parseInt(abtmTxt.getText().toString());
                        mucBritaNum = Integer.parseInt(mucBritaTxt.getText().toString());
                        meCimentoNum = Integer.parseInt(meCimentoTxt.getText().toString());
                        meBritaNum = Integer.parseInt(meBritaTxt.getText().toString());
                        meAreiaNum = Integer.parseInt(meAreiaTxt.getText().toString());

                        dmaxNum = Double.parseDouble(dmaxTxt.getText().toString());
                        mfNum = Double.parseDouble(mfTxt.getText().toString());

                        if(rcpNum == 0 ||
                           fckNum == 0 ||
                           abtmNum == 0 ||
                           mucBritaNum == 0 ||
                           meCimentoNum == 0 ||
                           meBritaNum == 0 ||
                           meAreiaNum == 0 ||
                           dmaxNum == 0 ||
                           mfNum == 0){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preencha todos os campos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Intent intentTraco = new Intent(v.getContext(), TracoActivity.class);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("rcpNum", (int)rcpNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("fckNum", (int)fckNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("abtmNum", (int)abtmNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("mucBritaNum", (int)mucBritaNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("meCimentoNum", (int)meCimentoNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("meBritaNum", (int)meBritaNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("meAreiaNum", (int)meAreiaNum);

                            intentTraco.putExtra("dmaxNum", (double)dmaxNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("mfNum", (double)mfNum);
                            intentTraco.putExtra("sdNum", (double)sdNum);
                            startActivityForResult(intentTraco, 0);
                         }
                    }
                });
                // CALCULAR #######################################

        } //fecha onCreate
    }
```

Segue o Logcat:

```
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566): Process: com.edeiltonso.dosapp, PID: 18566
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at com.edeiltonso.dosapp.HomeActivity$2.onClick(HomeActivity.java:70)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5141)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
12-14 20:47:40.367: E/AndroidRuntime(18566):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para validar se o campo está vazio use a propriedade `length`.
Da forma que você fez, você está (estava) comparando se o `EditText` é igual a 0.

---

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
if(rcpNum.length() == 0 ||
   fckNum.length() == 0 ||
   abtmNum.length() == 0 ||
   mucBritaNum.length() == 0 ||
   meCimentoNum.length() == 0 ||
   meBritaNum.length() == 0 ||
   meAreiaNum.length() == 0 ||
   dmaxNum.length() == 0 ||
   mfNum.length() == 0){  // o resto do código ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

O seu erro parece estar vindo destas linhas:

```java
                    rcpNum = Integer.parseInt(rcpTxt.getText().toString());
                    fckNum = Integer.parseInt(fckTxt.getText().toString());
                    abtmNum = Integer.parseInt(abtmTxt.getText().toString());
                    mucBritaNum = Integer.parseInt(mucBritaTxt.getText().toString());
                    meCimentoNum = Integer.parseInt(meCimentoTxt.getText().toString());
                    meBritaNum = Integer.parseInt(meBritaTxt.getText().toString());
                    meAreiaNum = Integer.parseInt(meAreiaTxt.getText().toString());
```

Observe o erro:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

Ou seja, uma `String` vazia está sendo passada para um dos `parseInt`s. Isso significa que pelo menos uma das `EditText`s está em branco. Em lugar nenhum você está validando se elas foram preenchidas e se foram preenchidas corretamente. E portanto, ocorre um erro quando uma delas não está preenchida de forma adequada.